# Postgres order column index

Tags: postgresql

I have table chapters where every chapter has it's unique id and order number:

chapters:

```
id | name   | book_id | order
1  | First  | 1       | 1
2  | Second | 1       | 2
3  | First  | 2       | 1
4  | Second | 2       | 2
```

I select this with query:

```
SELECT * FROM chapters where book_id=1 ORDER BY order
```

Do i need to create ordinary index on order column, or this index should be separated for every book somehow, because if i select 1000 chapters for 1 book, i don't need indexes for another books.

Or maybe there is a batter way to make one book chapters changeable ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try adding the following index to your table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON chapters (book_id, "order");
```

This should make it easy for Postgres to find records with a certain `book_id` value, and then to order the result set by the `order` column.

Note that `ORDER` is a reserved SQL keyword, so you should probably avoid using it to name your columns and tables.